# SQL Server 2017 crashed during startup on Ubuntu with Pacemaker failover

Tags: linux, sql-server, drbd, pacemaker, corosync

I have installed mssql-server and mssql-server-ha on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS. I'm using drbd on two nodes, with pacemaker and corosync attempting to control the automatic failover between the two nodes. `crm status` shows 2 errors:

```
Failed Actions:
* res_mssql_monitor_5000 on hostname2 'invalid parameter' (2): call=57, status=complete, exitreason='2017/11/09 12:33:01 Expected local server name to be res_mssql but it was hostname1',
last-rc-change='Thu Nov  9 12:33:01 2017', queued=0ms, exec=5241ms
* res_mssql_start_0 on hostname2 'unknown error' (1): call=6086, status=complete, exitreason='SQL Server crashed during startup.',
last-rc-change='Thu Nov  9 12:32:39 2017', queued=0ms, exec=24329ms
```

(actual host names replaced with "hostname1 and hostname2")

**TL;DR** 
If someone has successfully configured a two-node pacemaker/corosync/drbd  SQL Server 2017 on Linux setup with a floating IP, I'm interested to find out what I'm doing wrong. If you require additional config or log files please let me know.

---

I don't know where it's finding the actual hostname1 vs rs_mssql as the expected hostname. The above error is on hostname2, so I think it might have been when I copied a config file over from hostname1 to hostname2 during initial setup.

My crm configuration:

*(Note: I haven't attacked the IPaddr2 problem yet; I have ens160 and ens192 for my regular IP addresses, and I want to later configure an IP alias as ip_mssql for the public IP access to the SQL server)*

```
node 1: hostname1 \
   attributes
node 2: hostname2 \
   attributes
primitive ip_mssql IPaddr2 \
   params ip=(virt IP addr) iflabel=ip_mssql \ #I think iflabel is wrong
   op monitor interval=5s nic=ip_mssql \
   meta target-role=Stopped
primitive res_drbd_mssql ocf:linbit:drbd \
   params drbd_resource=mssql \
   op start interval=0 timeout=240s \
   op stop interval=0 timeout=120s
primitive res_fs_mssqlData Filesystem \
   params device="/dev/drbd0" directory="/var/opt/mssql/data" fstype=xfs \
   op start interval=0 timeout=60s \
   op stop interval=0 timeout=120s
primitive res_fs_mssqlLog Filesystem \
   params device="/dev/drbd1" directory="/var/opt/mssql/log" fstype=xfs \
   op start interval=0 timeout=60s \
   op stop interval=0 timeout=120s
primitive res_fs_mssqlTempDB Filesystem \
   params device="/dev/drbd2" directory="/var/opt/mssql/tempDB" fstype=xfs \
   op start interval=0 timeout=60s \
   op stop interval=0 timeout=120s
primitive res_mssql ocf:mssql:fci \
   op monitor interval=5s timeout=30s \
   op start interval=0 timeout=60s \
   op stop interval=0 timeout=60s
group mssqlserver res_fs_mssqlData res_fs_mssqlLog res_fs_mssqlTempDB ip_mssql
ms ms_drbd_mssql res_drbd_mssql \
   meta notify=true master-max=1 master-node-max=1 clone-max=2 clone-node-max=1
colocation col_mssql_drbd inf: mssqlserver ms_drbd_mssql:Master
order ord_mssql inf: ms_drbd_mssql:promote mssqlserver:start
property cib-bootstrap-options: \
   have-watchdog=false \
   dc-version=1.1.14-70404b0 \
   cluster-infrastructure=corosync \
   cluster-name=mssqlserver \
   stonith-enabled=false \
   start-failure-is-fatal=false \
   last-lrm-refresh=1510177588 \
   startup-fencing=true \
   enable-startup-probes=true \
   symmetric-cluster=true \
   stop-orphan-actions=true \
   stonith-action=reboot \
   remove-after-stop=false \
   stop-all-resources=false \
   stop-orphan-resources=true \
   no-quorum-policy=ignore \
   is-managed-default=true
```

I can manually start `mssql-server` just fine:

```
sudo systemctl start mssql-server
sudo systemctl status mssql-server

mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-11-09 12:49:21 CST; 1s ago
   Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
Main PID: 3368 (sqlservr)
   Tasks: 62
Memory: 171.0M
   CPU: 1.770s
CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
       3368 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
       3371 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr

Nov 09 12:49:21 hostname2 systemd[1]: Started Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
```

These are the only actual errors I found in `/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog`:

```
2017-11-09 12:49:28.17 spid4s      Service Master Key could not be decrypted using one of its encryptions. See sys.key_encryptions for details.
2017-11-09 12:49:28.17 spid4s      An error occurred during Service Master Key initialization. SQLErrorCode=33095, State=8, LastOsError=0.
2017-11-09 12:49:31.14 spid22s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2017-11-09 12:49:31.14 spid22s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2017-11-09 12:49:31.17 spid22s     Service Broker manager has started.
2017-11-09 12:49:31.37 spid4s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

Manual drbd failover works by `umount /dev/drbd0 /dev/drbd1 /dev/drbd2` and `drbdadm secondary mssql`, then reversing that process on the new primary (`drbdadm primary mssql` and mount...).

My /etc/drbd.d/mssql.res conf (/etc/drbd.d/global_common.conf is unaltered from repositories):

```
resource mssql {
   handlers {
            split-brain "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-split-brain.sh root";
   }
   net {
            after-sb-0pri discard-least-changes;
            after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
            after-sb-2pri disconnect;
   }
   volume 0 {
        device minor 0;
        disk /dev/VG-SqlData/LV-SqlData;
            meta-disk internal;
   }
   volume 1 {
       device minor 1;
       disk /dev/VG-SqlLogs/LV-SqlLogs;
            meta-disk internal;
   }
   volume 2 {
       device minor 2;
       disk /dev/VG-TempDB/LV-TempDB;
            meta-disk internal;
   }
   syncer {
            rate 35M;
            verify-alg md5;
   }
   on hostname1 {
            address <ip addr1>:7788;
   }
   on hostname2 {
            address <ip addr2>:7788;
   }
}
```

Comment: How are you starting MSSQL manually?

Comment: I've updated above to include `sudo systemctl start mssql-server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `systemd` to start the service instead:
`crm configure edit res_mssql`

Edit the config so it reads like this:

```
primitive res_mssql systemd:mssql-server \
   op monitor interval=30s timeout=30s \
   op start interval=0 timeout=60s \
   op stop interval=0 timeout=60s
```

That should accomplish the same thing. However, I would imagine the resource-agent could take a few additional parameters, which might be all that's needed to get it working the way you had tried.

I would suggest checking the RA info to see if you can figure out what parameters you're missing: `crm ra info ocf:mssql:fci`

Comment: Oh, I also adjusted the monitor interval because `5s` seems too tight

Comment: Thanks for the `crm ra` information. At the end of the file it states:
   ` Operations' defaults (advisory minimum):
    start         timeout=1000
    stop         timeout=20
    monitor.   timeout=30 interval=10`

So I changed those. I dove deeper into `/var/log/syslog | grep sql` and found:
    `Nov 15 14:21:40 hostname2 sqlservr[25694]: The SQL Server End-User License Agreement (EULA) must be accepted before SQL Server can start. ...
    Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`

So I think I have found my problem. Will post back here if not. Thanks again!